# PHP PDF combine with layers

Tags: php, pdf, ghostscript

I'm using the following PHP script to combine several PDF files into one which works fine. However several of the PDFs have multiple layers and only layer one is included in the combined output. Is there a way to maintain the layers in the output? Some of the online combine services can do it.

```
$fileArray= array("name1.pdf","name2.pdf","name3.pdf","name4.pdf");
$datadir = "save_path/";
$outputName = $datadir."merged.pdf";
$cmd = "gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=$outputName";
foreach($fileArray as $file) {
    $cmd .= $file." ";
}
$result = shell_exec($cmd);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'layers' ? PDF files don't have layers, though there are several (different) features of PDF which people refer to as layers. Perhaps you could share an example, its going to be hard to help without one. What version of Ghostscript are you using ? Do you get any messages in the back channel ?

Comment: You mean you get all teh data, but it is as one layer and you want to maintain the layers, or you mean that you only get one layers data and you want all of it (w/ layers or not).

Comment: The files are created in Illistrator and the different layers are saved along with it. When viewed in Adobe Reader you can turn off each layer as required from the layers panel. This may not be a PDF standard but it works well. When the files are combined, I want to maintain these layers but using my code, all the layers are combined into a single (flat) layer. All the content is there but the layers are no longer separate. Open this file in Adobe or similar and you can see the layers (page 2) - https://cncc.org.uk/caving/topos/files/0255570a-d43f-1acf-d338-f9579676bba1.pdf

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include the details added in your comment.  That said, I use `pdftk` to merge PDFs together.  I intentionally `flatten` mine and I don't create multi-layer PDFs either (I use FDF to fill them and generate certificates), but if I need to intentionally flatten, perhaps `pdftk` will leave your layers intact?